# SQL объединение запросов

Tags: mysql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ли способ объединить эти запросы в один?

Мне фактически необходимо добавить к 1 запроса еще одну колонку в которой будет выводиться количество архивных вакансий

Comment: `AND (vacancies.status = '...' OR vacancies.status = '...')`

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. важные подробности должны быть изложены непосредственно в тексте вопроса.

Comment: чего только в group by не увидишь, кроме выбранных полей

Comment: Объединить можно несколькими принципиально разными способами (UNION, JOIN, conditional aggregation, etc.). И из вопроса в принципе неясно, какой нужен.

Comment: Выложите пример данных (в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) и требуемый результат для именно таких данных. Форматированным текстом!!! а не фотографиями.

Comment: @Akina так там вроде запрос по одной группе и по второй нужен в одной выборке